# ITK setPixel meets heap corruption

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, itk

I have some questions about ITK.
I first create an image. Then I use "for" to set value of each pixel. And after, the problem show when program steps to "image->SetSpacing". VS2010 indicts this may be due to the corruption of heap. And when I don't use the "for" circulation there is no problem.

Can anyone help me?  I run the program in VS2010 and ITK 4.4.2

```
#include "iostream"
#include "itkImage.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef itk::Image<unsigned char,2> ImageType;
    ImageType::IndexType start;
    ImageType::SizeType size;
    start[0] = 0;
    start[1] = 0;
    size[0] = 100;
    size[1] = 150;
    ImageType::RegionType region;
    region.SetIndex(start);
    region.SetSize(size);
    ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();
    image->SetLargestPossibleRegion(region);
    image->Allocate();
    image->FillBuffer( 0 );

    for(int j=0; j<150; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            ImageType::PixelType pixelVal;
            pixelVal = i+j;
            ImageType::IndexType index = {{i,j}};
            image->SetPixel(index,pixelVal);
        }
    }

    ImageType::SpacingType spacing;
    spacing[0] = 0.1;
    spacing[1] = 0.4;
    image->SetSpacing(spacing);
    ImageType::SpacingType sp =image->GetSpacing();
    cout<<sp[0]<<' '<<sp[1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have set `size[1] = 200;` instead of `size[1] = 150;` since you are looping over 200 rows?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.I am sorry. This is a typing error. I have corrected now. There is no question for "for" circulation. The problem happens at image->SetSpacing(spacing).

Comment: I didn't try the code, but a suggestion is to try to set explicitely the index as   ImageType::IndexType index ;
  index [0] = 0;
  index [1] = 0;   (or at least print it for easier debugging, I've seen before code not crashing when a non-existent index was used and crashing later in another point of the program)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't use the `image->SetBufferedRegion(region)` method to set the region of the image located in memory.

You should replace the following line

```
image->SetLargestPossibleRegion(region);
```

with

```
image->SetRegions(region);
```

The `SetRegions()` method will simultaneously call the `SetLargestPossibleRegion()`, `SetRequestedRegion()` and `SetBufferedRegion()` methods with the region you give to it.

**You should always use `SetRegions()` when creating an image manually.**

---

Honestly I don't understand the full extent of this error. It is not at all obvious what goes wrong from the error given at runtime... only that there is some sort of error that occurs when the `image` object is being destructed. It has nothing to do with the `SetSpacing()` method or the way you assign to the `index` object.